# Parts of my code not working in "While" loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have a calculator in Python that will soon be able to do Algebra
I'm pretty new at Python so i might have messed up. The division, multiplication and exponent part of the code do not work while everything else does!

I've tried checking indents.
Not sure if "float" only works for certain operations?
as I said I'm pretty new.

```
 #MathPython v0.4 (c) 2019 UEG Productions################################################################################################################################
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
     input('Welcome to PyMath version 0.4!      >> Press [Enter] to continue <<' )
     input('Please Choose an option by typing it below  >> Press [Enter] to continue <<')
     operation = input('test score, +, -, /, *, <, >, **, help     Operation: ')

     ######here is where everything is executed!###############
     if operation == 'help':
          print('Welcome to the MathPython Help Guide!')
          print('Ensure you type the EXACT symbol or text of the funtion you want to be performed')
          input('Follow directions carefully!     >>')
          print('If any other questions are present please contact us at ########@gmail.com')
     if operation == 'test score':
          print('Two values are needed to find the test score')
          print('Please type in the total amount of questions on the test')
          totalqs = int(input('Total: '))
          print('Now, type the number of questions you got correct')
          correctqs = int(input('Correct: '))
          pct = float(correctqs / totalqs * 100)
          print('you got a(n) ' + format(correctqs) + ' out of ' + format(totalqs))
          print('That is equivelent to ' + format(pct) + '%')
          if format(pct) <= 70:
               print('You Better study! Your grade was below a 70% Which is below average')
          else:
              print('Good job on the test, keep it up!')
     if operation == '+':
          print('First value?')
          add1 = int(input('VALUE 1: '))
          print('Second value? ')
          add2 = int(input('VALUE 2: '))
          added = float(add1 + add2)
          print(format(added))
          input('Operation done! >>Press [Enter] to go continue<<')
#SUBTRACTION ---- "add" is just a variable so don't confuse it!
     if operation == '-':
          print('First value?')
          add1 = int(input('VALUE 1: '))
          print('Second value? ')
          add2 = int(input('VALUE 2: '))
          added = float(add1 - add2)
          input(format(added))
          input('Operation done! >>Press [Enter] to go continue<<')
#Division
     if operation == '/':
          print('First value?')
          add1 = int(input('VALUE 1: '))
          print('Second value? ')
          add2 = int(input('VALUE 2: '))
          added = float(add1 / add2)
          input(format(added))
          input('Operation done! >>Press [Enter] to go continue<<')     
 #Multiplication
     if operation == '*':
          print('First value?')
          add1 = int(input('VALUE 1: '))
          print('Second value? ')
          add2 = int(input('VALUE 2: '))
          added = float(add1 * add2)
          input(format(added))
          input('Operation done! >>Press [Enter] to go continue<<')      
 #Exponents
     if operation == '**':
          print('First value?')
          add1 = int(input('VALUE 1: '))
          print('Second value? ')
          add2 = int(input('VALUE 2: '))
          added = float(add1 ** add2)
          input(format(added))
          input('Operation done! >>Press [Enter] to go continue<<')
```

No error messages, just keeps looping back to the beginning when I do certain operations

Comment: what are the operations that are causing looping?

Comment: Could not reproduce. Addition, multiplication, division, subtraction, and exponentiation work as expected. Please clarify what the error is.

Comment: how do you want to exit the calculator? i.e. `loop` is never set != 1

Comment: You never set the `loop` variable to anything besides 1, so you will never break out of your `while` loop. I would recommend changing your `input` statements at the end of each operation to include the name of the operation so you can keep better track of where the execution flows through the script.